# Cable spirals in then coil compresses animation

Tags: animation, path

Im working on a cable animation where I need a cable to spiral up a coil, then have the coils compress down. Like the coils laying down on one another.  I can get the cable to come in and go up the coil and I can select the coil path and compress it to do what I want but im not sure how to get that to animate. Any help would be appreciated as I am very new to blender. Thanks

[image]
Cable goes up the stretched coil

[image]
Then need cables to compress and do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're already using a curve modifier on a mesh to do this, which is convenient.  You can use hooks:

[image]

In edit mode on your curve, you can select a control and its handles then ctrl-h -> hook to new object.  This create a new empty and a new hook modifier that links the selected control and handles to the empty, which can then be animated.

Repeat for every control in your curve:

[image]

Now make a new empty at the base of your curve and parent all these new empties to it.  Do not parent the mesh object or the curve to it.  Just the empties.

By scaling this parent empty-- something that is keyframable-- you can move the positions of all of the curves, by moving the positions (and scale) of the child empties.  Here, I am scaling that parent in only its Z axis:

[image]

Without affecting the radius of the curve.

To slide the mesh object along the curve, regardless of whether the curve is compressed or not, move the mesh object in its deform axis (from the curve modifier; default is X axis).  In object mode.

[image]

You now have controls to compress the coil, from the scale of the hooks' parent, and to slide along the curve, from the translation of the mesh object.  You can keyframe scale or location as appropriate on either of these objects.

Edit: after thinking for a second, you don't need individual hooks for this-- you can hook all controls and handles to the empty at the base of the curve.  (I just tend to use curves for other purposes, with fewer controls, but they all need to be hooked.)

Comment: This hook method worked perfectly! thanks for the help!

Comment: @RyanB This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the coil is supposed to move up? If it's not the case, ignore the first steps and only use shapekeys.

Create your spiral, in the *Data* panel > *Geometry > Bevel* > give it *Depth*, enable *Fill Caps*, at frame 0 keyframe the *Factor Start* at 0 and *Factor End* at 0.5 for example:

[image]

At frame B keyframe the *Factor Start* at 0.5 and *Factor End* at 1:

[image]

Create 2 shapekeys, select the second shapekey, squeeze the curve on Z, and at frame C keyframe the *Value* of second shapekey at 0:

[image]

At frame D keyframe the *Value* of second shapekey at 1:

[image]

Result:

[image]